# How to create dataset using prop.table?

Tags: r

I would like to create a dataset comprised of frequencies created using prop.table. How would I go about doing this? dataset is here https://gofile.io/d/QuqKh5

```
(prop.table(table(sample$day12))*100),
(prop.table(table(sample$day13))*100),
(prop.table(table(sample$day14))*100),
(prop.table(table(sample$day15))*100),
(prop.table(table(sample$day16))*100)
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
structure(list(day12 = c("5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", 
"4 = High", "5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", "4 = High", "4 = High", 
"5 = Very High", "4 = High"), day13 = c("5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", 
"5 = Very High", "4 = High", "5 = Very High", "4 = High", "4 = High", 
"4 = High", "5 = Very High", "4 = High"), day14 = c("4 = High", 
"5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", NA, "3 = Medium", 
"4 = High", "3 = Medium", "4 = High", "4 = High")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Ultimately I need to produce a graph like this, which shows the percentage of 4=High and 5=Very High (combined)[image]

Comment: Instead of asking us to download an Excel file and import it to help you, please construct a small reproducible sample of data that is copy/pasteable, and put it in your question. `dput()` is very helpful for this. Something like `dput(sample[1:10, c("day12", "day13", "day14")])`, or a subset similar to that to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
structure(list(day12 = c("5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", 
"4 = High", "5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", "4 = High", "4 = High", 
"5 = Very High", "4 = High"), day13 = c("5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", 
"5 = Very High", "4 = High", "5 = Very High", "4 = High", "4 = High", 
"4 = High", "5 = Very High", "4 = High"), day14 = c("4 = High", 
"5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", "5 = Very High", NA, "3 = Medium", 
"4 = High", "3 = Medium", "4 = High", "4 = High")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Yes - that's super helpful. I can copy/paste that into my R session and get a subset of your data. Now that's taken care of, what is your goal? A data frame with... one row per `day` and 1 column for each category, with the `prop.table` proportion as the value? Or with one row per category and one column per `day`? Or one column for day, one for category, one for proportion? Something else? It'd be great if you could show the expected output for that small sample input you shared with `dput()`.

Comment: So, I updated my question to include a picture of my end graph. I need to produce a graph that shows the percentage of 4's and 5's (combined) for each variable. I had been manually calculating the percents and final dataset, but wondered if there's a way to automate this?

Comment: In your graph do you want one bar per day?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2):

This should get you well on your way. First we convert the data to long format, then summarize it (I include the missing values as not high ratings - you may want to handle them differently), and finally plot it.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

## with dplyr and tidyr
sample_summarized = sample %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "day", values_to = "rating") %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  summarize(high_proportion = mean(grepl("High", rating)))

## with base
prop_high = sapply(sample, function(x) mean(grepl("High", x)))
sample_summarized = data.frame(high_proportion = prop_high, day = names(prop_high))

ggplot(sample_summarized) +
  aes(x = high_proportion, y = day) +
  geom_col(fill = "#104E8B") +
  geom_text(
    aes(x = high_proportion / 2, label = scales::percent(high_proportion, accuracy = 1)),
    color = "white"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for me to do this in base R? Specifically, just the part where I get the data ready to enter into barplot.

Comment: Added a base method for creating the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could do :

```
barplot(colMeans(sapply(df, grepl, pattern = 'High')) * 100)
```

[image]